# Errors in the image resize class Visual c#

Tags: c#, image, resize, puzzle

I'm trying to make a puzzle game in microsoft visual c# 2010 and when I try to resize the image to fit the groupbox I get these errors:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
'System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image,
System.Drawing.PointF)' has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PuzzleImage.Form1' to
'System.Drawing.Image'

error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
'System.Drawing.Rectangle' to 'System.Drawing.PointF'
```

**NOTE**: The errors are in the 2nd part of the code, int the private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(Form1 image) class.

Here is my code:

```
   OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = null;
    Form1 image;
    PictureBox picBoxWhole = null;

    private void buttonImageBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog == null)
            openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName); 
                if(picBoxWhole== null)
                {
                    picBoxWhole= new PictureBox();
                    picBoxWhole.Height = groupboxPuzzle.Height;
                    picBoxWhole.Width =groupboxPuzzle.Width;
                    groupboxPuzzle.Controls.Add(picBoxWhole);
                }
            picBoxWhole.Image= image;
        }
    }

    private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(Form1 image)
    {
        Bitmap objBmpImage = new Bitmap(groupboxPuzzle.Width, groupboxPuzzle.Height);
        Graphics objGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(objBmpImage);
        objGraphics.Clear(Color.White);
        int x = groupboxPuzzle.Width;
        int y = groupboxPuzzle.Height;
        objGraphics.DrawImage(image,  new Rectangle(0,0, x, y));
        objGraphics.Flush();

        return objBmpImage;

    }
```

And here is [the tutorial](http://jetgamedev.blogspot.ro/2012/05/lesson-0229-c-lab-4-create-image-puzzle.html) that I am currently following. Also someone said something about an error at 77 step too.

Comment: Well, read your errors and you'll know why they are happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you transferring a `Form` parameter in your `CreateBitmapImage()` function? It says in that tutorial to accept `Image` type parameter.

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(Image image)
```

Comment: Indeed, but the image has the same size. Anyway thank you very much. I'll have to do the tutorial again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
 Form1 image; to  Image image; //only if you need this :)
```

and

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(Form1 image) to private Bitmap CreateBitmapImage(Image image)
```